# "Не хватает штата"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Правильно же так, а не во множественном — *штатов*?

Comment: В словарях *сокращение штатов* (хотя это не устойчивое выражение, но логика мн.ч. не объясняется), а в солидной литературе и так и этак бывает.

Comment: @grizzly: а в гугле раз в пять больше в единственном, если закавычить.

Comment: Кроме ответа oleed, есть еще вариант. Человек смотрит на карту США или другой страны, которая состоит административных единиц, называемых штатами, и видит отсутствие на карте одного штата. Такой вариант может быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ОТВЕТ

1. Язык – вещь упрямая, так как  он ориентируется на практические нужды пользователей. Поэтому в русском языке  мирно существуют две формы – ***штат и штаты,*** причем по утверждениям словарей форма мн. числа может употребляться в значении ед. числа.

А что это значит? Мы можем говорить так, как нам больше нравится?  В некоторых случаях формы взаимозаменяемы, а иногда можно **допустить ошибку,** выразиться неверно.

Штат предприятия  – это фактически **список** всех подразделений и структур с указанием должностей работников и их количества в каждой структуре. Поэтому **общий список (штат)** составлен из ряда **входящих в него  списков**, отсюда возникает противопоставление **ед. и мн. числа.**  Поэтому нужную форму мы выбираем по смыслу, по ситуации.

**2.  Начнем с вопроса**

***Не хватает штата? Правильно же так, а не во множественном — штатов?***

Да, правильно именно так. На предприятии недостаточное **общее количество** работников  (каких конкретно – об этом не говорится). А общая численность – это именно штат (ед. число).

**3. Рассмотрим другие фразы**

**Сокращение штатов.** В этом случае рассматриваются списки отдельных структур и определяется оптимальное количество работников для каждой структуры. **Утвердить штаты, пересмотреть штаты** – аналогичная ситуация, то есть утверждаются списки подразделений (проводится работа со списками).

Должности дизайнера **нет в штате**, то есть эта должность не предусмотрена на предприятии вообще. **Пополнить штат, зачислить  в штат, подобрать штат** – здесь также говорится об общем количестве работников, то есть о штате.

СПРАВОЧНЫЕ МАТЕРИАЛЫ

**Штатное расписание** — это документ, фиксирующий структуру, должностной (профессиональный) состав и штатную численность организации.

КАКИЕ СВЕДЕНИЯ ВКЛЮЧАЕТ В СЕБЯ ШТАТНОЕ РАСПИСАНИЕ?

•   наименование организации и документа;
•   номер документа, дату составления и период действия;
•   наименование и код структурного подразделения;
•   должность (специальность, профессия) с указанием разряда, класса, категории или квалификации в случае наличия;
•   количество штатных единиц по каждой должности (специальности, профессии);
•   тарифная ставка (оклад) по каждой должности (специальности, профессии);

Таким образом, в штатном расписании мы можем увидеть, какие структурные подразделения существуют в данной организации, какие должности (профессии) и в каком количестве закреплены за каждой структурой.

Comment: Браво! Прекрасный ответ! Остальным тоже спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Спасибо,  Артем!!!

Comment: По утверждениям каких словарей?

Comment: Кузнецова и Ушакова.

Answer (score 3):

Да, правильно.

Словарь:
II 1) Постоянный **состав сотрудников** какого-либо предприятия.
*Штат учителей тридцать человек.*

Так и в других словарях.

Если более точно, то штат — просто сотрудники, никак не один сотрудник, чтоб говорить "штатов".

Но фраза разговорная.

Есть некоторые выражения, где употребляется множественное под влиянием разговорной речи. В других случаях его употреблять не стоит.

Словарь Ефремовой:
штаты *мн. разг.*
*Документ, определяющий число сотрудников какого-либо учреждения с указанием их должностей, функций и окладов; штатное расписание.*
Это вполне можно применить и к составу. То есть разговорный вариант, он используется при увеличении количества, подборе сотрудников.

Comment: *Так и в других словарях* — в каких? Вы видели хоть один официальный толковый словарь, в котором к толкованию "Постоянный состав сотрудников..." не предлагают пример _сокращение **штатов**_? И какой именно словарь Вы цитировали?

Comment: Не видел, то устойчивое сочетание. Они часто примеры берут из других словарей. Словарь Кузнецова.

Comment: *Расширение штатов, утверждение штатов*, тысячи других подобных выражений, которые встречаются в документах самого высокого уровня строгости — это всё устойчивые сочетания? Ладно, спорить с Вами себе дороже. Хорошо (наверное), что Вы не копируете эти тупые словари — намного удобнее фальсифицировать цитаты в угоду собственным умозаключениям.

Comment: Тысячи вы не найдёте, вряд ли более десятка. А что спорить? Тогда надо признать, что "штат" — один сотрудник, то есть что в словарях либо неверное значение, либо не хватает значения. Не понял мысль в последнем предложении. Что за "тупые словари"? Что за фальсифицирование?

Comment: Вы скопировали словарную статью из Кузнецова (толкование и 2 примера употребления), а потом удалили из неё среднюю часть (один из примеров, который опровергает Ваше умозаключение). Вы будете утверждать, что выполнили эти действия неосознанно?

Comment: Ответ обновлен. Ответы здесь превращаются в создание проблем самому себе из-за таких, как вы. Опровергайте сказанное, а не критикуйте образно. Если не согласны с чем-либо, скажите с чем и почему. А не так, что у меня всё не так и всё не то.

Comment: Мне не интересно Вас опровергать. Я указываю Вам на на систематические и однотипные ошибки, которые Вы постоянно допускаете в своих ответах. Не обращайте внимание на мою критику, если не хотите. Я только надеюсь, что мои комментарии помогают другим участникам лучше разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Нет у меня таких ошибок. Словарное определение должно соответствовать примерам, а здесь не так, раньше с таким не сталкивался. И тире в этом примере должно стоять. Хотелось бы, чтоб ваши указания были конкретными, а не расплывчатыми (менее приятно). А то ваши заумно закрученные фразы, чтоб обидеть, аж раздражают, это о том же предложении.

Comment: *Мне не интересно Вас опровергать* — просто вы не в состоянии, в том числе опровергнуть то, что истинно.

Comment: Не слишком фразы и заумные, если включить немного мозг, то все понятно, что grizzly говорит. И он точно не хочет обидеть. Если бы он хотел, то сразу задрал бы насмерть)

Comment: @user190920 Заумные, чтоб культурно попустить и выглядеть при этом интеллигентным и умным. Дело никак не в том, что трудно понять.

Comment: Что поделать, не притворяться же ему, что он неинтеллигентный и дурной.

Comment: @user190920 Дело не в этом, таким образом можно делать разные пакости (прикрываясь интеллигентностью).

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что корни проблемы лежат в распространённом конфликте литературного словоупотребления и профессионального узуса (в данном случае это делопроизводство). Насколько я понимаю, в канцелярите слово "штаты" может выступать синонимом выражения "штат сотрудников". Но вопросы делопроизводства настолько широко проникают в бытовую сферу, что его терминология распространяется и закрепляется.

Словари по-разному фиксируют проникновение узуса в литературный язык, и с этим мы сталкивались на форуме неоднократно. Иногда распространяющийся узус относят к разговорному стилю, иногда дают в качестве примеров употребления. В словаре Кузнецова (и в большинстве других словарей) приведен пример словоупотребления **сокращение штатов**. Те, кто уже пользовались ранее словарём Кузнецова, знают, что это именно пример употребления, а не устойчивое выражение (это объясняется в "кратком руководстве к пользованию" в начале словаря). Такое же решение предлагают словари Ожегова, Ушакова и некоторые другие.

Словарь Ефремовой предлагает другое решение: разговорный стиль. Тоже не бесспорное решение, поскольку большинство грамотных носителей языка вряд ли согласится с тем, что выражение **штатное расписание** (приведенное там в качестве примера) не достойно литературного стиля.